# Set view defination in a ListTemplate?

Tags: list-template

I've created a ListTemplate based off of a custom content type in Visual Studio for a document library.  The content type adds two fields, a fiscal year and a fiscal month.  It adds it to the template fine and the user is prompted correctly after uploading a doc for those fields, but the default view that is used when a new list is created from this list template does not include those fields.  Is it possible to get those fields added to the default view?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow the MSDN article [How to: Create a Custom List Definition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466023.aspx) in the part "Create the List Definition from the Content Type" step 5 and 6 describes how to add fields to the view:

> Step 5. Next, open the Schema.xml file that was created.
>    Step 6. In the ViewFields element, add the same FieldRef element that you added to the content type. The following XML adds a reference to the field.
>   `<FieldRef ID="FieldId" Name="FavoriteColor" />`